# Identity Server for validating more than one application using WSO2

Tags: wso2, cxf, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 ESB and Identity Server. I have a requirement. Let me put this way. I have 2 application running on 3 different server (tomcat). One and Two are Web application and the another one is Web service.

1. I want to login to first web application using identity server.
2. First webapp will call second one. that time second web app should validate the user
3. And second web app will call the web service and web service should validate the request whether it is made by a used who is logged in properly.

Since I am confused with Saml, open id configuration and all

Can any one please help me on the following

1. How to configure the WSO2IS server for the same.
2. When first webapp call the second web app how to pass the validate token (or xml)? Is it as a form data or http header?
3. How to do the same with Web service application

Thanks
Sreekumar

Comment: In your #2 step, the First webapp calls the Second webapp. How does the first webapp call the second one ? Is it a web browser redirect ?

Comment: no it will be using a HttpClient which will trigger a ESB (that is deployed in mule currently).

Comment: So the second webapp is just a rest API, in the perspective of first webapp. Is that so?

Comment: yes, it will be making a request to Web service within that app.

Answer (score 0):

http://suhothayan.blogspot.com/2012/12/single-sign-on-across-web-applications_8.html?m=1

This will solve your problem, if there are any doubt, just ask